# Verb forms, and the usage of commas

Tags: sentence-construction

I'd rather stay at home, read more books.

I'd rather stay at home reading more books.

I'd rather stay at home, and read more books

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: 1 needs to be like 3. In 1 you could use a semi-colon and skip the conjunction (though it would be odd in this example).

Answer (score 2):

> I'd rather stay at home, read more books.

This form would probably never be used.  It is an unnatural phrasing.  Phrased this way "read more books" sounds like an imperative.

> I'd rather stay at home reading more books.

This one is much better.

> I'd rather stay at home, and read more books

This one is also correct, and is probably the most likely form that would be used.  Though the comma in the sentence is unnecessary. 
Per [rule 3c from this site](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp)

> If the subject does not appear in front of the second verb, a comma is generally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

They all have the same meaning, just with varying levels of correctness or formality.

---

> I'd rather stay at home, read more books.

This one feels informal and stilted, almost like you thought of the last half of the sentence after saying the first. Still, something like that is fairly common in ordinary speech. I'd punctuate it like this, though I'm not sure it's a standard way to do so:

> I'd rather stay at home...read more books.

---

> I'd rather stay at home reading more books.

It's a little unnatural to use "more" like this after "reading". "More" than what? Than someone else? Than you would if you weren't at home?

---

> I'd rather stay at home, and read more books.

I think this is the most correct, natural, and clear of the three sentences.